# How can i do send bulk of list within one E-mail on App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to do send an email that will go to the customer and he or she will see that which product has arrived in the office,

First, I am gathering the values from my Sheet like that (part of that code);

```
var partReceivedQuerySheet = uyg.getSheetByName("Part Received Query");
var partReceivedQuerySheetLastRow = partReceivedQuerySheet.getLastRow();
var indexSupplierName = partReceivedQuerySheet.getRange("A2:A"+partReceivedQuerySheetLastRow).getValues();
```

I am using the MailApp function, I want to send that email like table, for that reason I am using
HtmlBody, and my code like that (part of that code);

```
'<table>'+
'<tr>'+
'<td>'+indexSupplierName+'</td>'+
'</tr>
```

I tried for loop before MailApp function but that time it is sending number of suppliers name mails,
I tried the For loop before MailApp, but at that time it sent as many e-mails as the number of suppliers one by one.

Based on Ron M answer I did Supplier Names like my input. My code is;

```
  var indexSupplierNames =partReceivedQuerySheet.getRange("A2:A"+partReceivedQuerySheetLastRow).getValues().flat(); 
  var indexProductNames =partReceivedQuerySheet.getRange("B2:B"+partReceivedQuerySheetLastRow).getValues().flat();
  var productInfoTable = '<table border="2"><tr><th><b>Brand</b></th>';
  productInfoTable+='<th><b>Product Name</b></th>';
  productInfoTable+='<th><b>Quantity</b></th>';
  productInfoTable+='<th><b>Arrived to Warehouse?</b></th></tr>';
  indexSupplierNames.forEach(supplierName=> {

  productInfoTable+='<tr><td>'+supplierName+'</td></tr>'

   });  
   productInfoTable+= '</table>';
```

I have Product Names, Quantity, and one more column on My Sheet, I want to add all to the table, but when I try that forEach() thing I can not align Product Names with Supplier Names.

Finally, [the output that I want to like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJUp5.png). I am sorry about that, I am noobie in AppScript but I tried really so much and I could not add it.

Comment: It sounds like you will have one for loop for selecting different recipients and another for loop nested inside of that one that builds the table a data.   Make sure you don't put send mail inside of the inner loop.  There are numerous examples of nested for loops.  Do some research.  If I do it for you then you will never learn how to do it yourself.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and your desired output?

Comment: A sample sheet would help as well

Comment: @RonM I could not add image on the post because I am new here I could only add a link on the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your expected output. The supplier names' should be written on a different table rows `<tr></tr>`

### Here is a sample code:

```
  var partReceivedQuerySheetLastRow = partReceivedQuerySheet.getLastRow();
  var indexSupplierName = partReceivedQuerySheet.getRange("A2:A"+partReceivedQuerySheetLastRow).getValues().flat();
  Logger.log(indexSupplierName);
  var email = 'youremail';

  var hmtlContent = '<table border="1"><tr><td><b>Brand</b></td></tr>';

  indexSupplierName.forEach(name => {
    hmtlContent += '<tr><td>'+name+'</td></tr>';
  });
  hmtlContent+='</table>';
  Logger.log(hmtlContent)

  MailApp.sendEmail(email,"Test","",{htmlBody: hmtlContent});
```

### What it does?

1. I changed the `Range.getValues()` return from 2-d array into a 1-d array.
2. Created a starting html table content
3. Loop all supplier names. Append each name on a different row in the html table content

### Output:

[image]

### (Update:)

How to create and update the table with multiple columns:

```
var indexSupplierNames = ["Supplier1", "Supplier2", "Supplier3"]; 
  var indexProductNames = ['Product1', 'Product2', 'Product3'];
  var productInfoTable = '<table border="2"><tr><th><b>Brand</b></th>';
  productInfoTable+='<th><b>Product Name</b></th>';
  productInfoTable+='<th><b>Quantity</b></th>';
  productInfoTable+='<th><b>Arrived to Warehouse?</b></th></tr>';

  for (var i=0; i<indexSupplierNames.length; i++){
    productInfoTable+='<tr><td>'+indexSupplierNames[i]+'</td><td>'+indexProductNames[i]+'</td><td>0</td><td>No</td></tr>'
  }
  productInfoTable+= '</table>';
  Logger.log(productInfoTable);

  MailApp.sendEmail("your@email.com","Test","",{htmlBody: productInfoTable});
```

### Output:

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered an issue so I could update the answer

Comment: Thank you so much to do this, I understand now, I need to learn forEach function, thanks again :)

Comment: Glad to hear that. By the way, If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: Thank you for the warning, I marked that button.

Comment: Based on Ron M answer, for one row is working correctly but, when I want to add product name and quantity to that supplier names, the script can not align that so it is not working, based on my output, how can I add Product Name, Quantity within aligning?

Comment: It should be something like this `<tr><td><b>Brand</b></td><td><b>Product Name</b></td><td><b>Quantity</b></td></tr>`. Please read [HTML tables](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)

Comment: Thank you for reply but i read and tried maybe 50 times but I could not. My problem is forEach() function, I can not add the others, when I try nested forEach the table is okay but Supplier names are writing the other columns, I give up for that situation :(

Comment: can you share a sample sheet with your current code that contains sample input data

Comment: Please see the updated answer. take note that the solution will work assuming the supplier names, product names, quantity and arrive info have the same data length. I temporarily just used a default value for the quantity and arrive info but it should be the same on how I updated supplier and product name column

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved it like that thank you to Ron M for help me to learn.

Code;

```
productInfoTables = '<table border="2"><tr><th><b>Brand</b></th>';
productInfoTables+='<th><b>Product Name</b></th>';
productInfoTables+='<th><b>Quantity</b></th>';
productInfoTables+='<th><b>Arrived to Warehouse?</b></th></tr>';

for (var k=2;k<=partReceivedQuerySheetLastRow;k++){
var supplierNames = partReceivedQuerySheet.getRange(k,1).getValue();
var productNames = partReceivedQuerySheer.getRange(k,2).getValue();
var qty = partReceivedQuerySheet.getRange(k,3).getValue();
var arrivedToWarehouse = partReceivedQuerySheet.getRange(k,4).getValue();
productInfoTables+= '<tr<td>'+supplierNames+'</td>'+'<td>'+productNames+'</td>'+'<td>'+qty+'</td>'+'<td>'+arrivedToWarehouse+'</td></tr>'
}
```